# Free 3d character models to edit in Blender

Tags: import

Rocmen here, a newbie. I was wanting to import 3d character model like a man 
and modify it and then animate it. Is that possible in Blender?

Thanks for any help

Rocmen

Answer (score 0):

short answer : yes
look at https://www.blendswap.com/ you find lot of character to play with, some even rigged. Your at the beginning of your journey :) Welcome!